# How to make a table from nested loops in python to html

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Python Code:

```
trailDict = {}
    for i in range(numTrails):
        for key in selectTrail[i].items():
            currentTrail = selectTrail[i]
            didkey = 'id'+str(i+1)
            dnamekey = 'name'+str(i+1)
            dlocationkey = 'location'+str(i+1)
            didvalue = currentTrail['id']
            dnamevalue = currentTrail['name']
            dlocationvalue = currentTrail['location']
            trailDict.update({didkey:didvalue})
            trailDict.update({dnamekey:dnamevalue})
            trailDict.update({dlocationkey:dlocationvalue})
return render_template('trails.html',response = response,form = form,city = city, lat = lat,
     long = longit, numTrails = numTrails,selectTrail = selectTrail, latlong = latlong, trailDict = trailDict)
```

HTML Code:

```html
<table align="center" style="width 80%">
    <tr>
        <th>KEY</th>
        <th>VALUE</th>
    </tr>

    {% for key,value in trailDict.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{key}} </td>
        <td> {{value[loop.key]}} </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

[the picture is displaying after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjVA3.png)

So, i cannot get the values to show up on the table. it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your HTML code like this:

```html
<table align="center" style="width 80%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>KEY</th>
                        <th>VALUE</th>
                    </tr>

                        {% for key,value in trailDict.items() %}
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{key}} </td>
                            <td> {{value}} </td>     
                        </tr>
                       {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: thank you. it clicked right when I posted the question.